# Mudar a cor do textview usando switch

Tags: android

Eu gostaria de saber como mudar a cor de um *texview* usando um *switch*. Ao selecionar o *Switch*, a palavra do lado se destaca com outra cor no *Android Studio.*

**Código do XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:checked="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:checked="false" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Código Java:**

```
package com.example.apoll.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

O código cima seria para mudar a cor do *Hello world*, e quando clicar de volta, retorna para a cor "original".

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro para receber o evento de check/uncheck do `Switch` você precisa implementar a interface `OnCheckedChangeListener` através do método `setOnCheckedChangeListener`, dentro desse `callback` você tem acesso a um `boolean` que indica se o `Switch` está 'checked' ou 'unchecked', a partir daí você pode alterar o `TextView` para a cor que você desejar

```
final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
Switch switch1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);

// Uma forma de salvar a cor 'original' do TextView
final ColorStateList oldColors =  textView.getTextColors();

switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                // Verificando se o switch está marcado, caso esteja, alterar a color para 'Color.RED', caso não, restaurar para cor 'original' do TextView
                if (checked) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                } else {
                    textView.setTextColor(oldColors);
                }
            }
        });
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6468764/4181975